# Showing red color for required field controls after calling form.reset() in angular material

Tags: angularjs, angular-forms

[Attached screenshot for more information about error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADJdU.png)

I am using FormGroup to create form Controls and after submitting filled data to the server I am calling form.reset() Method to clear current data.
So what I want, that all controls should be rendered as like when a component initializes for the first time

Html file code:

```
<mat-form-field>
     <input matInput id="title" placeholder="Enter your title" 
     formControlName="title">
</mat-form-field>
```

TS file code:

```
title: new FormControl("", Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
      ])),
```

Comment: can u provide more code

Comment: you can use $scope.form={ } to reset  the input fields when clicking the submit function

Comment: Is that $scope.form = {} is available in Angular 4?

Answer (score 0):

This is **angular5**:

```
  <form [formGroup]="myform" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

**js**

```
onSubmit()
{
if(this.myform.valid)
{
console.log("form submitted",this.myform.value)
this.myform.reset();
}
}
```

see this link for more [check the link](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/forms/submitting-and-resetting/)

Comment: No. The form gets reset successfully but that red line under required field control still there (Attached in above screenshot)

Comment: Is there any way to clear the input fields values of Material forms than form.reset() method

Comment: you can clear the input field values by the $scope.form.name

Comment: Showing a syntax error for the $scope. Should I use one class with form parameter and after submitting initialize the class each parameter with empty value?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46168337/how-to-clear-all-the-md-input-fields-at-once-inside-a-md-form-using-an-external